# Measure sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{C} = \{[a_1,b_1)\times\ldots\times [a_n,b_n) : -\infty  \leq a_i,b_i \leq \infty \}$, if $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n,\{J_k\}_{k=1}^l$ are elements in $\mathcal{C} $ such that $I_k \cap I_j,J_k \cap J_j = \emptyset$ when $k$ is different from $j$. Prove that if $\cup^l J_k = \cup^n I_k $, then 
$$\sum^l m(J_k) = \sum^n m(I_k) $$

I was tryning to proof this but I don't have any adie about how to proceed, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is any additive function i.e. $m(A\cup B) =m(A) +m(B) +m(A\cap B).$ Then it is easy to prove that $$m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^s A_k \right)=\sum_{k=1}^s m(A_k ).$$

So let $L=\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k =\bigcup_{k=1}^l I_k$ then

$$\sum_{k=1}^l m(J_k )=m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^l J_k \right)=m(L)=m\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k \right)=\sum_{k=1}^n m(I_k ).$$